# If statement with 2 dates in Swift

Tags: swift, date, if-statement

I'd love to show a SwiftUI view only if the current day number is equal to the day number stored on my CoreData attribute.

I've first tried this line below but it seems to not be possible:

```
if (example.date!, format: .dateTime.day(.twoDigits)) == (Date(), format: .dateTime.day(.twoDigits)) {
```

Then, I've tried this line below that I've found on Internet:

```
if Calendar.current.isDate(example.date!, equalTo: Date(), toGranularity: .day) {
```

But it's not working as expected. This is fine only if the dates are both `04/02/2023` but not if the dates are `04/02/2023` and `05/02/2023`.

Do you guys have an idea? Thanks!

Comment: Use DateComponents

Comment: I think the OP is using American dates so `04/02/2023` means 2nd April and not 4th February. They only want to compare the day number, ignoring the month and year and that is why the isDate toGranularity code does not so what they want. As lorem ipsum has said, the solution is to extract just the day number using `DateComponents`.

Comment: Goeff is right about the American dates. Also, `inSameDayAs:` isn't working as expected neither. I'll try `DateComponents` if it's not that hard. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a helper function as an extension of `Date` which checks the value of a specific date component for equality

```
extension Date {
    func isValueOfComponent(_ component: Calendar.Component, equalTo date: Date) -> Bool {
        Calendar.current.component(component, from: self) == Calendar.current.component(component, from: date)
    }
}
```

then compare

```
if example.date!.isValueOfComponent(.day, equalTo: Date())
```

---

A more flexible solution which is able to consider multiple components is

```
extension Date {
    func isDateEqual(to date: Date, matching components: Set<Calendar.Component>) -> Bool {
        Calendar.current.dateComponents(components, from: self) == Calendar.current.dateComponents(components, from: date)
    }
}
```

and use it

```
if example.date!.isDateEqual(to: Date(), matching: [.month, .day])
```

Comment: Thanks! It's working very fine. I've also found this: https://www.zerotoappstore.com/how-to-check-if-two-dates-are-from-the-same-day-swift.html if it can help someone else.

Comment: `dateComponents(_: from:,to:` considers also the more significant components, it works like `inSameDayAs:`.